# What is difference between synchronous vs asynchronous and blocking vs non-blocking IO. Does they both speak about same concept?

Tags: asynchronous, io, blocking, synchronous, nonblocking

I am reading about multithreaded servers in Java and communication in it. I have the above query as "What is difference between synchronous vs asynchronous and blocking vs non-blocking IO. Does they both speak about same concept?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronous I/O = blocking I/O

Asynchronous I/O = non-blocking I/O